# Ошибка zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file при работе в openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, openpyxl

С помощью get запроса я по прямой ссылке хочу получить xlsx файл, далее я его сохраняю вот пример кода

```
import openpyxl
import requests
import config
b = '08.01.2020'
login = config.login
password = config.password
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://exapmple.ru/login"
r = s.post(url, data=config.data)
url2 = f'https://example.ru/admin/claims.xls?startDate={b}&finishDate={b}'
resEDS = s.get(url2)
resEDS1 = resEDS.content
with open("for_daily_report_EDS.xlsx", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(resEDS1)
```

Далее я пытаюсь его редактировать с помощью openpyxl:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('for_daily_report_EDS.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
print(sheet['A2'].value)
# sheet.delete_rows(2)
wb.save('for_daily_report_EDS.xlsx')
```

Но получаю ошибку: `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

Погуглив я понял, что проблема в том, что при записи через write не добавляются метаданные в файл, говорящие о том, что это файл xlsx.
То есть если зайти в Свойство файла --> Особые, то тип файла будет указан как текстовый. При открытии файла в libreoffice  и последующем сохранении ошибка исчезает.

Как справится с этой ошибкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нашел решения вопроса, поэтому отказался от использования openpyxl и читаю файл с помощью pandas. Так даже намного удобнее.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import config
b = '08.01.2020'
login = config.login
password = config.password
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://exapmple.ru/login"
r = s.post(url, data=config.data)
url2 = f'https://example.ru/admin/claims.xls?startDate={b}&finishDate={b}'
resEDS = s.get(url2)
resEDS1 = resEDS.content
with open("for_daily_report_EDS.xlsx", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(resEDS1)
df = pd.read_excel("for_daily_report_EDS.xlsx")
```